# How to read a 2d array from a file without knowing its length in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, end-of-line

Like the title says I'm trying to read an unknown number of integers from a file and place them in a 2d array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

fstream f;int i,j,n,a[20][20];char ch;

i=0;j=0;n=0;
f.open("array.txt", ios::in);
while(!f.eof())
{
    i++;
    n++;
    do
    {
        f>>a[i][j];
        j++;
        f>>ch;
    }
    while(ch!='\n');
}

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        cout<<a[i][j]<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

and my "array.txt" file :

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

After compiling the program, it prints this

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `while(ch!='\n')`? Edit: Also, you may want to flip the order of the `f>>ch` and `f>>a[i][j]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't post links to output, post the actual output. Try something simpler first: reading to a simple (1D) array. Don't use `while(!f.eof())`.

Comment: I will try your suggestions. Edit : It doesn't return anything.

Comment: `std::vector` seems to be right tool for the job.

Comment: You are going to have issues because the `operator>>` appears to discard whitespace by default. Try using `getline(file_descriptor, cpp_string)`.

Comment: @forkrul sry to annoy you , but can you be a little more specific , I'm really nothing more that an amateur at c++;

Comment: @FalconLover see my answer for what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your input file is line oriented, you should use `getline` (C++ equivalent or C fgets) to read a line, then an `istringstream` to parse the line into integers. And as you do not know *a priori* the size, you should use vectors, and consistently control that all lines have same size, and that the number of lines is the same as the number of columns.

Last but not least, you should test eof **immediately after** a read and not on beginning of loop.

Code becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    fstream f;
    int i=0, j=0, n=0;
    string line;
    vector<vector<int>> a;
    f.open("array.txt", ios::in);
    for(;;)
    {
        std::getline(f, line);
        if (! f) break; // test eof after read
        a.push_back(vector<int>());
        std::istringstream fline(line);
        j = 0;
        for(;;) {
            int val;
            fline >> val;
            if (!fline) break;
            a[i].push_back(val);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        if (n == 0) n = j;
        else if (n != j) {
            cerr << "Error line " << i << " - " << j << " values instead of " << n << endl;
        }
    }
    if (i != n) {
        cerr << "Error " << i << " lines instead of " << n << endl;
    }

    for(vector<vector<int>>::const_iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); it++) {
        for (vector<int>::const_iterator jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); jt++) {
            cout << " " << *jt;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using a vector so you can have a dynamic array.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  fstream f;
  int i, j, n, a[20][20];
  string buf;

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  n = 0;
  f.open("array.txt", ios::in);
  while (1) {
    getline(f, buf);
    if (f.eof()) break;
    stringstream buf_stream(buf);
    j = 0;
    do {
      buf_stream >> a[i][j];
      j++;
    } while (!buf_stream.eof());
    i++;
    n++;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also, if you really want to read arbitrarily large arrays, then you should use `std::vector` or some such other container, not raw arrays.

Comment: Recommend a tweak: `while (getline(f, buf))` in place of `while(1)`, the separate `getline` and the `if` and `break`. Also prevents the admittedly rare case of stream error in `getline` without eof resulting in undefined contents in `buf`.